# whats wrong with my dark theming

Tags: themes

The title bars look like:
[image]

and in the system settings, i have no option for dark theme:
[image]

I was trying to do this: https://gist.github.com/fardjad/a1ec470712150e8d3d67693911f5afb8. but just after the first step, this happened: